# In TYPO3 6.x, how to get defaultJS, when config.disableAllHeaderCode is enabled?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-6.1.x

I set `config.disableAllHeaderCode = 1` in my recent TYPO3 sites, as I want full control over the page template.

But this not only throws out the html tag etc., but also the default Js (which could be used to uncrypt mailto-Links.

One solution would be to copy this TYPO3-generated JS from the core code and insert it manually. Very simple: just set `config.disableAllHeaderCode = 0`, load the page once, copy the js, done. But, in case of an update or settings change, this might break.

So: is it possible to access this "default JS" via typoscript and assign it to the PAGE object?

Comment: This mainly refers to the js function linkTo_UnCryptMailto for email address obfuscation/encryption (adding this for better findability)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Page/PageGenerator.php. You will see that the spam protection code is hardcoded and only added to the page output if config.disableAllHeaderCode is *not* set.

Therefore I don't see a possibility to do that. Therefore the answer seems to be no, unless you XCLASS the PageGenerator. I would just copy the JavaScript code; I'm using TYPO3 for some years now and wouldn't remember that the spam protection code ever changed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution I think. Go to /typo3/sysext/cms/tslib/templates. There is a file tslib_page_frontend.html. This file is responsible for rendering the whole page including the head. You can define a new path to the above mentioned file. For example set the following code:

```
config.pageRendererTemplateFile = PATH_TO_YOUR_THEME//Resources/Private/Core/tslib_page_frontend.html
```

respectively

```
page.config.pageRendererTemplateFile = PATH_TO_YOUR_THEME//Resources/Private/Core/tslib_page_frontend.html
```

The new template file can look like the following small snippet:

```
###JS_INLINE###
###BODY###
```

That way the inline JS is still rendered (and I think the spam protections JS is inline JS - which can be stored in external files).

Comment: I think you're right! I haven't tried it out yet, but looks sensible

Answer (score 0):

years later, finally, it's much easier.
In **TYPO3 v12** the script can be included as a single file which resides in `EXT:frontend/Resources/Public/JavaScript/default_frontend.js`.